# python - MultiValueDictKeyError Django form data not being posted

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to build a simple form where users can place their address. When the form is submitted, I get an error saying:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /store/order/ 
"'street'"
```

I believe that the data for the street address is not properly getting submitted, which is strange because I know that the `street` input is not empty. When I try to replace `street = request.POST['street']` with `street = request.POST.get('street', '')` everything is marked as empty, so I know the data is not being posted. This happened at first periodically, but now it's constant. Any thoughts?

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":

        street = request.POST['street']
        street_num = street.split(" ", 1)[0]
        city = request.POST['city']
        state = request.POST['state']
        zip_code = request.POST['zip']
        street_name = street.split(" ", 1)[1]

        order.shipping = str(street_num) + " " + str(street_name) + ", " + str(city) + " " + str(zip_code) + ", " + str(state) + ", " + 'US'
```

form.html

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/order/' method="POST" id="shipping-form">{% csrf_token %}
                <span class="lead">Shipping Address</span>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                  <label class="upper text-dark">
                    <span>Street Address</span>
                    <input id="street" name="street" type="text" size="50" placeholder="'123 Artist St'">
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <label class="upper text-dark">
                    <span>City</span>
                    <input id="city" name="city" type="text" size="50" placeholder="'San Francisco'">
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label class="upper text-dark">
                    <span>State</span>
                    <input  id="state"name="state" type="text" size="2" placeholder="'CA'">
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                  <label class="upper text-dark">
                    <span>Zip Code</span>
                    <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" size="4" placeholder="'12345'">
                  </label>
                </div>
              </form>
```

I am aware I don't have a `<input type="submit">` tag. I have multiple forms, so the submits are being handled in javascript. However, my other forms are working, and they look the exact same, so I am confused as to why this one won't work

Edit: Javascript (I am using Stripe for payments, so this is executed right after the Credit form is submitted)

```
document.getElementById("shipping-form").submit();
```

Comment: Can you print your `request.POST` and see if there's anything in it? Also can you post your form submission code?

Comment: maybe your javascript code doesn't handle inputs correctly? Put a breakpoint and see what is in `request.POST`.

Comment: show us your JS

Comment: @Hybrid Updated Question

Comment: @ozgur I have a duplicate form to handle billing addresses, and the javascript that submits it works perfectly, again a duplicate of the shipping address. It's just this one form in particular that doesn't want to POST the data properly.

Comment: @user2564732  I suggest you to include <input type="submit"> inside form tag and trigger a click event of that button, don't forget to make this button submit type, and you are getting this error becouse there not any key like this in the dictionary as you can read here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__